# simplifying overloaded class function

Tags: c++, overloading

I am having in my class gTexture two functions declared:

```
public:
                               gTexture():mActiveTexture(0){...}
   virtual void                DrawTexture();
   virtual void                DrawTexture(unsigned short int TextureNumber);
           int                 mActiveTexture;
```

where

```
void gTexture::DrawTexture()
    {
    gTexture::DrawTexture(mActiveTexture);
    }
```

I'd like to have this in one function something like

```
virtual void                DrawTexture(unsigned short int TextureNumber=mActiveTexture);
```

This does no compile as mActiveTexture is an invalid use of non static data member. Is there any way to just have one function, which would make it easier to handle with my derived objects? Thanks.

Comment: What is `void foo() : x(y) {...}`?

Comment: @juanchopanza it's an initializer, can only be done on the constructors

Comment: @wich `DrawTexture` is not a constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza exactly

Comment: @wich so it is not an initializer, it is gibberish :)

Comment: @juanchopanza it's still an initializer, it's just invalid use of one

Comment: yea.. I messed that one up when typing.. I meant to have a constructor there.. (edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two ways. Both are workaround-ish, but could be useful.

One is to make the parameterless function non-virtual; it will simply always call the second one with `mActiveTexture`.

The other way is to use domain knowledge (specifically the fact that `0` is not a valid OpenGL texture name) and do this:

```
virtual void DrawTexture(unsigned short int TextureNumber = 0) {
  if (TextureNumber == 0) TextureNumber = mActiveTexture;
  // ... rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I think default parameters in virtual member functions are too scary.

Comment: @juanchopanza indeed it's problematic to say the least, the default value is compile time and the one used depends on the type of the pointer/reference not of the actual object.

Comment: ohh great help, thanks. But that second local makeshift won't work. [0] refers to the first element of a vector of textures in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a default argument value that is not valid (e.g. -1).  Then your function can check if that value is the default and if it is, use mActiveTexture, otherwise it will use the argument.

Comment: that's a good idea but dangerous considering that I use arrays and -1 could crash my program. I used to have it everywhere but turned away from -1 in my whole program for that reason

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use members as defaults. Defaults are used at compile time.

You could however use a special value for the default, like -1 and then check in DrawTexture if the input values is -1 and if so set it to mActiveTexture.